# Automapper List to CustomCollection

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map 2 Entities. One has a List of strings and other one is using a custom collection. Can anybody please advice how can I map these 2 entities using AutoMapper.

```
 public class SourceItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<string> ShipsTo { get; set; }
}

public class DestItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MyCollection ShipsTo { get; set; }
}

public class MyCollection : CollectionBase
{
    private readonly List<string> _list;

    public MyCollection()
    {
        _list = new List<string>();
    }

    public MyCollection(List<string> list)
    {
        _list = list;
    }

    public void Add(string item)
    {
        _list.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Here is my mapping code...

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceItem, DestItem>()
    .ForMember(d => d.ShipsTo, o => o.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());
 });
```

Here is how my custom resolver looks like...

```
public class CustomResolver : IValueResolver<SourceItem, DestItem, MyCollection>
{
    public MyCollection Resolve(SourceItem source, DestItem destination, MyCollection destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return new MyCollection(source.ShipsTo);
    }
}
```

When I try to run this code, I get an error saying

> No coercion operator is defined between types
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' and 'MyCollection'.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Seems like Automapper has bug. But anyway - why do you need to inherit `CollectionBase`?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy This is just for example. Actually I am using a 3rd party API (eBay SDK) and they have a lot of collections that are using CollectionBase like the example I have posted. I can't change their custom collections.

Answer (score 0):

I could  not really explain it, but it works, if you define explicit mapping configuration from `MyCollection` to `MyCollection`:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<MyCollection, MyCollection>().ConvertUsing((a,b)=>a);

    cfg.CreateMap<SourceItem, DestItem>()
            .ForMember(d => d.ShipsTo, o => o.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());
});
```

I have debugged code of automapper to find why. Reason is, Automapper is looking for suitable mapper to map `MyCollection` to `MyCollection`. It looks in a collection of all mappers (defined in your config and predefined). Actually, what it should find is a `AssignableMapper`, that just assigns one variable to another, but first he checks an `EnumerableMapper` and it looks ok, because your `CollectionBase` is `Enumerable`. The exception comes from this `EnumerableMapper`, because it just couldn't map this two Collections. Solution is to explicit define, that it just should assign one variable to another.

[image]

**But. I am agree with Sergey. This is some ugly bug, what i have suggested is exact the same ugly workaround**. But i've managed get it to work :)

Comment: Error goes away, but there is no mapping - MyCollection is empty

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I have changed answer, now on my sample it worked.

Comment: The suggested code doesn't gives error but MyCollection is still empty. Even after doing .ForMember(d => d.ShipsTo, o => o.MapFrom(src => new MyCollection(src.ShipsTo)));

Comment: Debuggin shows that MyCollection is called twice for some reason. 1st time with MyCollection(src.ShipsTo) which adds items to the list and second time it calls the default constructor which re-initiates the list.

Comment: @nafr1 how do you see, that collection iis emty? your code inherits collectionBase but don't use it. You should look on private _list property, it is set, after i map it.

Comment: @nafr1  Ok, i stil don't have solution, collection is mapped,  becase i have added a function for getting a list (for debug purpose):             public List<string> GetList()
            {
                return _list;
            }  Automapper from some reason see it and use

Comment: @MaksimSimkin : Yes I am aware of that. I am checking the private readonly List<string> _options; and it's empty.

Comment: @nafr1  I managed to it without public getter and updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you need a custom resolver, try this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceItem, DestItem>()
    .ForMember(d => d.ShipsTo, o => o.MapFrom(src => new MyCollection(src.ShipsTo)));
 });
```

Comment: You are right, i think, he wrote customresolver trying to avoid exception. You will get it with your code too.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: you cannot use custom value resolver here, because there is a bug (I have added item to [backlog](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1905), you can track it). But you can specify conversion between `List<string>` and `MyCollection` as Jimmy suggested. And everything will work fine:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<List<string>, MyCollection>().ConvertUsing(s => new MyCollection(s));
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceItem, DestItem>();
});
```

BTW Seems like issue already fixed, and it should be available in next release of Automapper.